# Java Lambda: Class with type?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm very new to Lambda, and I would like to have a Generic class done so like a non-generic class. Take for example the Runnable, it isn't generic:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    // code here
}
```

And I had a Generic class, how would I do it in Lambda just like I can with a non-generic class?

```
MyGenericClass<T> generic = ...
```

Comment: `Runnable` is not generic

Comment: I know it's not, but what would I do for lambda if a class had a generic type? Does lambda even allow me to do that?

Comment: Yes. The lambda type is a [`FunctionalInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) (though the annotation itself is not mandatory). See [Function<>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) or [Predicate<>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) for examples of easy-to-understand generic functional interfaces.

Comment: Lambdas which implement generic functional interfaces are declared the same way. [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) doesn't have any type parameters. What are you trying to achieve? You may need to use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Comment: You can find some info about target typing in the [lambda expressions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing)

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas use generics and type inference heavily. So much so that type inference was add to Java 8 to make the syntax more readable.

Let me give you an example

```
// this adds a dynamic reference to this method
Predicate<String> isEmpty = String::isEmpty;
```

or

```
// this creates a new lambda static method and 
// creates a dynamic reference to that method
Predicate<String> isEmpty = s -> s.isEmpty();
```

or

```
Predicate<String> containsX = s -> s.contains("X");
```

These are used by Stream.filter()

Answer (score 1):

There's an example [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html) where they use:

```
Callable<String> c = () -> "Hello from Callable";
```

and

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Collections.sort(list,
        (x, y) -> x.getLastName().compareTo(y.getLastName()));
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Essentially - the lambdas in java 8 take the type intuition that was introduced in Java 7 to the nth degree. It is really quite astonishing how effective it is in working out the types of complex expressions.